# How could I answer to the question: "Why are you leaving your company?" without looking conceited?

Tags: interviewing, work-environment, colleagues, italy

I'm planning to look for another job.

I am a programmer.

I have a lot of reasons, but some of them, which are important to me, and not only salary related, make me think a bit.

For example:

1) All the other Companies offer me an higher salary (+300€ in average).

2) My actual company thinks they can pay me lower because of my age. This makes me feel like I'm actually wasting my time, I won't gain more money ever and I will never grow up in career here.

3) I always end my tasks in time or earlier. From their point of view, this makes me a "nothing doing" employee respect to another guy which works on the same task for days without even doing a good work.

4) I'm the only one making documentation.

5) I'm the only one respecting conventions.

6) I'm the only one programming in English.

7) If you open our SVN all the new projects of the last 2 years are projected and developed by me.

8) My Project Manager left the company, other colleagues too, we aren't enough to cover all the needs.

9) Everytime I have to work on an existing project, I find variables named like "a", "abc", "jkdj", 100000 lines of code in a single file without even being ordered. There is NO documentation, and in most of the cases nobody even tell me where can I find the project (sometimes they don't know the name too ...) and I have to look for it, in our SVN, in 12898498 directories.

10) I know that I'm the person with the lowest salary in my office, but at the same time, they all ask for my help because I have more "know how" than them in programming (I am a "pure programmer" they all started their careers as system administrators).

11) Actually a colleague of mine, which is not so skilled (and we all know it), has been made my "not officially recognized" superior and it is really stressing for me, because I feel like my work is minimized, I have to explain everything 50 times because she doesn't have the skills to understand and it's even unacceptable (for me), that I have to be under someone (doing my same job) who can't even read a stacktrace.

12) Our Sector Manager started to ask me for a daily detailed email about my work and I'm the only one doing it. This makes me feel even less appreciated.

13) Our Sector Manager told me he recognized my skills and I deserved an higher salary. I never received it. This made me feel even angrier.

---

Considering the possibility to face new job interviews, how could I answer to the question: "Why are you leaving your company?" without looking conceited?

I'm sure I can look conceited by hearing these words for someone who doesn't live my situation.

Comment: 100,000 lines of code in a single file? Seriously? Ok, I have seen one case where they stored Truetype fonts in a C array of char, so that was a few hundred thousand lines of "code" in about ten files.

Answer (score 6):

It's very simple:

> My new position offers more opportunity for growth, as well as a compensation level more in line with my skill level.

Honest, not belittling, and doesn't leave any "ambiguity" which some would see as opportunity for negotiation / coercion.

Comment: And don't forget the "The culture of the work didn't fit with me"